# Hebrew characters in AJAX header

Tags: javascript, ajax, utf-8

I'm sending file with AJAX to some server like:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: 'http://' + address + '/api/file/upload',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false, 
            headers: {
                "apiKey": "myKey",
                "FileName": "קובץ.txt"
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {}});
```

Code works fine, but when I put an Hebrew file name at the header I'm getting the error:

> Error Scan fileTypeError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Value is not a valid ByteString

Header: `"FileName": "קובץ.txt"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to encode the text to utf8 like:

```
unescape(encodeURIComponent(yourText)) //encode

decodeURIComponent(escape(yourText)) //decode
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319694#c9, it seems like headers are restricted to 
ASCII characters. If you are trying to pass a UTF-16 value to the endpoint, consider making it part of the POST body.

If you must keep the value as a header, you can also Base 64 encode the file name and decode on the server side. Here's an [example of base-64 encoding בוקר](https://www.base64encode.org/enc/%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%A8/)